# sich auf etwas vorbereiten/einrichten/einstellen

Tags: word-choice

Ich habe seit langem versucht, den Unterschied zwischen »sich auf etwas vorbereiten/einstellen/einrichten» herauszubekommen, aber ohne Erfolg. Sie werden alle als "get prepared/ready for something" auf Englisch übersetzt. Vom Gefühl her, glaube ich, dass die Variante »einrichten« etwas mehr mit einer geistigen Vorbereitung zu tun hat, aber da bin ich mir nicht ganz sicher. Vielleicht kann ich ein paar Beispiele anbieten:

1. Wir sollen uns auf eine lange Wartezeit einrichten/einstellen.
2. Ich habe mich nicht auf eine Party (Gäste, etc.) eingerichtet/eingestellt.
3. Die Wohnung ist auf eine Party eingerichtet/eingestellt.

Es wäre hilfreich, wenn man mir sagen könnte, welches Wort in den obigen Sätzen passt, und wo der Unterschied liegt.

Comment: 2. würde ich eher mit einem Zustandspassiv sagen - "Ich bin nicht auf Gäste eingerichtet"

Answer (score 1):

Lass uns eindeutigere Beispiele verwenden.

**Vorbereiten** ist der Schritt, der vor dem **(zu-)bereiten** kommt.

> Mama hat das Essen vorbereitet. *(Alles ist zum Kochen bereit.)*
>
> Mama hat das Essen bereitet. *(Das Essen steht auf dem Tisch.)*

Hier kann man weder *einstellen* noch *einrichten* verwenden, da diese Worte in ihrem Kern eine andere Tätigkeit beschreiben.

---

**Einstellen** bedeutet im Kern, etwas an die richtige Stelle zu bewegen.

> Sie stellt die Herdplatte auf fünf (ein). *(Das passt genau!)*
>
> Sie hat sich/ist auf Gäste eingestellt. *(Sie hat passend eingekauft.)*

Man kann im zweiten Satz zwar auch *vorbereitet* verwenden, allerdings verliert man dann den tieferen Sinn, dass alles *passend* vorbereitet wurde.

---

**Einrichten** zielt hingegen darauf ab, dass alles bereits da ist, wo es hingehört.

> Die Küche ist für Kochen und Essen mit der Familie eingerichtet. *(Sehr funktionell.)*
>
> Auf viele Gäste ist sie hingegen nicht eingerichtet. *(Kein Platz.)*

Auch hier kann man wieder **vorbereitet** verwenden, das klingt aber ein bisschen seltsam, weil es ja um Möbel geht. **Eingestellt** geht auch, ist aber noch seltsamer.

---

Und nun alles im übertragenen Sinn. Vorsicht, Fußball:

> Der Gegner hat uns große Kopfschmerzen bereitet, und darauf waren wir nicht vorbereitet.
>
> Wir hatten uns darauf eingerichtet, dass alles über die Flanken laufen würde.
>
> Auf die vielen Angriffe durch die Mitte haben wir uns dann eingestellt, aber zu spät.

Comment: *Das Essen vorbereiten* ist aber nicht das gleiche, wie sich *auf das Essen vorbereiten*, was auch die Esser tun können. Dass in Beispiel *einstellen* *passend vorbereitet* bedeutet, während *vorbereiten* nicht unbedingt *passend eingestellt* bedeutet halte ich für Quatsch. Auch wenn man im Einrichtungshaus Möbel und nicht Kaffee und Kuchen kauft, kann man sagen, man sei auf 4 Gäste nicht eingerichtet, wenn man nur 2 Stück Kuchen hat. Wenn man 5 Stühle hat, aber einen noch aus dem Erdgeschoss hochtragen muss, wird man auch sagen können, auf so viel Besuch sei man gerade noch eingerichtet.

Comment: Was die letzten 3 Sätze zeigen sollen - *offensichtlich Unterschiede* würde ich sagen, wüßte ich es als Muttersprachler nicht besser, ist unklar. Satz 1: Es waren nicht alle Spieler da? Satz 2: Hier geht es um Möbel? Satz 3: Wenn die Umstellung auf Angriffe durch die Mitte nichts gebracht hätte, würde man nicht *einstellen* sagen, sondern *einrichten*?

Comment: Could the following be true:

1. sich auf etwas einrichten = get yourself set up for something. For example, I would say, "I need to get myself set up for a party", with the IMPLICATION that we actually need to get the HOUSE set up. Wir mussen uns auf eine Party einrichten. So, "einrichten" is not something you do to people. 

So, the sentence "Wir hatten uns darauf eingerichtet, dass alles über die Flanken laufen würde." actually implies that the DEFENSE is set up.

2. sich auf etwas einstellen is simply, "be ready for" ? Having the closest connection to vorbereitet?

Comment: *Sich auf etwas einrichten* can also be done to people, it means changing your mindset then. The second soccer sentence means exactly that, the defense was set up a certain way. The third one with *einstellen* means they changed a setting. So the verbs can all mean *to be prepared* but they have another meaning which is more specific in other contexts.

Comment: Ok, whew! (German is difficult haha). Would the following sentence

Wir müssen uns auf den herannahenden Sturm einrichten

be translated both as

We need to get (mentally) prepared for the oncoming storm, AND

We need to get (the house) prepared for the oncoming storm?

Comment: Yes, it can mean both. The difference is not so much in mind vs house but in planning. *Einrichten* is something which takes more effort than *einstellen*.

Comment: @Janka Darf ich dir noch eine Frage stellen? Es tut mir Leid, ich will nicht laestig sein. Wenn ich sage, ich stelle mich auf etwas ein, bedeudet das, dass ich anfange etwas Neues als eine Moeglichkeit/Gefahr/etc. zu halten und ich neue Elementen zu meinen Vorbereitungen (entweder geistig oder physisch, etc) hinzufuegen?  Und wenn ich sage, ich richte mich darauf ein, dann weiß man etwas mehr konkret was vor ihm steht (Gaeste, Sturm, etc.), und macht sich schnell dafuer bereit, oder schon dafuer bereit ist?

Comment: *Einstellen* bedeutet, dass du an einer einzelnen Schraube drehst. *Einrichten* bedeutet, dass du einen größeren Umbau vornimmst.

Answer (score 0):

Es passen alle, auch *vorbereitet*.

Ohne das *auf etwas* gibt es in eingeschliffenen Sprachgebrauch, etwa *die Wohnung einrichten* (Mobiliar auswählen und platzieren), *eine Maschine einrichten* als Montagetätigkeit, wenn es mit Schraubenschlüssel etc. geschieht aber wenn man nur Knöpfe dreht oder auf einem Display Werte manipuliert eher *einstellen*.